# How to have an AnchorBar with icons and subsections?

Tags: sapui5

I need to make a design exactly like this one https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageTabNavigationMode but with a slight difference.

The difference is adding icons in the Anchor Bar tabs not just the text.

I've tried the customAnchorBarButton aggregation but I also want to have sub-sections...
And I think it doesn't work anymore...

Thank you :)

Comment: Is it a freestyle or Fiori elements application?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Freestyle!